# 'SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' from ol-ext in Typescript Jest tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, openlayers

I'm using the openlayers extension library ol-ext in my application. It works fine when I run the application, but I'm having problems when trying to run my tests. When the tests are run, and the object is attempting to be created, I'm getting the following:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import ol_ext_inherits from '../util/ext'
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier



      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (../../../node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/private/geomap-ol/interaction-edit.ts:1429:41)
```

I've tried modifying my "transformIgnorePatterns" in the jest config to include the ol-ext, but that caused issues with openlayers not resolving:

current jestconfig.json:

```
{
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
        "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.svg$": "jest-svg-transformer",
        "^.+\\.xml$": "jest-raw-loader"
    },
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": ["src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/src/index.ts", "<rootDir>/node_modules/"],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!(ol)/)"],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fifteen",
    "setupFiles": ["jest-canvas-mock"]
}
```

tried jestconfig.json:

```
{
    ...
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!(ol|ol\\-ext)/)"],
    ...
}
```

and

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!(ol|ol\\-ext)/)", "node_modules/(?!(ol\\-ext)/)"],
```

Both of these versions caused the ol library to stop being ignored as well.

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                targets: {
                    node: 'current',
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```

I'm expecting that the ol-ext library can be used during tests as well so that I don't have a large block of untested code.